# How do I load damn cookies in the WKWebView decidePolicyFor navigationAction?

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview

cy) -> Void) {

attempts to
navigationAction.request
setValue("Cookies": ...

in

public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPoli

has no effect
(setCookie likewise has no effect on that webview configuration)

Any ideas? ios 12 and 13

Comment: are you sure you need to do it in decidePolicyFor?
I load cookies before loading url

```
webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(someCookie) {
// load url
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure when I need to load this particular cookie.

Comment: ok, then try to call decisionHandler on setCookie completion closure
`webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(someCookie) { decisionHandler(.allow) } `

Comment: i belive that would yield usage error to not call decisionHandler in decidePolicyFor navigationAction or to call it twicely

Comment: I don't tell you to not call or call twice, call it once in setCookie completion closure

Comment: i just faced the problem: setting cookies doesn't work in ios12, it's ok with 11,13,14, but 12 fails.